# display tooltip on hover for each row

Tags: angular, angular-material, angularjs-directive

I am displying data in grid view, below is screenshot of that.

Now I want to display tooltip on hover of each row, so any idea how I can get done that ?

[image]

Comment: You can do that by implementing it. Also please be aware of the tags you use. Angular is not compatible with angularjs, but you use both as tags in your question.

Comment: @cloned I need some starting guidance like I need to implement this in ngAfterViewInit or in Onit function.. once I get that then I can keep this going..

Comment: You can find enough of this guidance if you know how to use google (or any other search engine) This is not the type of question this page is for, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on what is a good question for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using angular material, you can use [tooltip component](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview):

- import `MatTooltipModule` into your module
- add `matTooltip="Info about the action"` directive on your rows

Without more information we cannot help you. You should share your code with your framework's versions

Comment: I am using generic-ui grid and below is code to show that grid..  <gui-grid `[source]="source"
      [columns]="columns"
      [loading]="loading"
      [paging]="paging"
      [sorting]="sorting"
      [searching]="searching"
      [titlePanel]="titlePanel"> 
    </gui-grid>`